# Why does signal-desktop require 4755 with root:root on chrome-sandbox?

Tags: signal-messenger

When I run `signal-desktop`, now I am getting,

> `[2615:0926/162216.901688:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)]` The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that `/opt/Signal/chrome-sandbox` is owned by root and has mode 4755.

Why does signal need a "sandbox helper" that runs as root:root to run a messaging application? Is this safe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Signal is an Electron application, which basically runs in a dedicated instance of Chrome. In order to contain the application, Chrome uses a sandbox, which needs to be setuid root so that it can set up the sandbox (which does seem paradoxical). There’s some discussion of this [in the Electron issue tracker](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972); in summary the Electron developers argue that it’s *more* secure to run Electron applications in a Chrome sandbox, using a setuid helper, than it would be to run them without.

As of `signal-desktop` version 1.27.2, you can also run by using the `--no-sandbox`:

```
signal-desktop --no-sandbox
```

Comment: Ty for your comment, but just a question nornagon's comment (link: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972#issuecomment-486927073 ) one have to change some configuration in order to not have to add this privilege again and again? Becuase if I change the execution privileges I have to redo it after reboot. Really strange and do not really understand what he mean..

Comment: @Salviati I’m not sure what you’re referring to — `sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1`?

Comment: A follow-on question (for the Signal team) is, why does your Debian/Ubuntu package not come with this executable properly configured "out of the box"?

Comment: To answer my own question, the Signal [developers say](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/3627), "We will not be forcing a root setuid on our users". They did, however, add a `--no-sandbox` flag to work around the problem.